# avcodec_decode_video2: what do the extra bytes prevent?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, decoding

In the [documentation for avcodec_decode_video2](http://ffmpeg.sourcearchive.com/documentation/0.6/avcodec_8h_3e4048fd6893d4a001bdaa3d251f3c03.html) it gives the following warning:

> Warning:
>
> The input buffer must be FF_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE larger than the
> actual read bytes because some optimized bitstream
> readers read 32 or 64 bits at once and could read over the end. The
> end of the input buffer buf should be set to 0 to ensure that no
> overreading happens for damaged MPEG streams.

If this were not implemented would this cause segmentation faults when overreading occurs? Or would it potentially cause weird corruption? I'm just curious as I have corruption and I'm not sure if this could potentially be causing my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wouldn't necessarily cause segmentation faults, but it would be `undefined behavior`, since these readers would be reading unallocated memory. This could make the program crash immediately, or work for a while, or even appear to work fine: you can never be sure when it comes to `undefined behavior`.

Comment: hypothetically speaking this means that it could just produce garbled glitchy output then correct?

Comment: Accessing memory you don't own is always a programming error. Hypothetically, literally anything could happen. Your assumption is not wrong, though.

Comment: Yeah I realize I am going out on a limb, but I'm just not sure how to check if it is reading over the container anyways. If I knew it was supposed to segfault then I could rule it out. Now that I know there is the potential for it to be over reading without me knowing, I know it is worth it to adding the FF_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE 0's onto the end

Comment: Yeah, you should always be careful when it comes to cases like these. They can get quite hard to debug after you pass through them.